# Mongoose save an array of objects in Ref schema

Tags: node.js, mongodb, mongoose

I've got the `Parent` Schema:

```
const parentSchema = new Schema({
   name: {
   type: String,
  },
 children: [{
    type: Schema.Types.ObjectId,
    ref: "Children"
  }]
})
```

And this is the `Children` Schema:

```
const childrenSchema = Schema({
  name: {
   type: String
  },
  surname: {
   type: String
  }
})
```

I have an incoming user register `POST` request in the following format:

```
{
 "name": "TEST", 
 "children" : [
    { "name":"test","surname": "test" },
    { "name":"test","surname": "test" }
 ]
}
```

Here's the router:

```
 router.post("/register", (req, res, next) => {
  const {name, children} = req.body;
  let newParent = newParent({
    name,
    children
   });
  newParent.save((err, result) => {
    // res.send(result) etc.
  })
 }
```

This results in the following error:

`Cast to Array failed for value "[ { name: 'test', surname: 'test' } ]" at path "children"`

How can I save all `children` and keep in the `ref` only the children `_id` so i can later `populate` the `Parent` collection?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> To save childData in Parents, You need to save first child's data in children schema Then get childIds and save to Parent Data.

**Working Example:**

```
let req = {
    "name" : "TEST", 
    "children" : [
       { "name":"test","surname": "test" },
       { "name":"test","surname": "test" }
    ]
   }

   Children.collection.insert(req.children, function (err, docs) {
    if (err){ 
       conasolw.log(err);
    } else {
      var ids =  docs.ops.map(doc=>{ return doc._id});;
      console.log(ids);
      let newParent = Parent({
        name : req.name,
        children : ids
       });
       newParent.save((err, result) => {
         console.log('parent save');
         console.log(err);
         console.log(result);
      })
    }
  });
```

Note :

> Test on `"mongoose": "^5.3.3"`

Answer (score 1):

The children field in the parent is expecting an arrays of ObjectIds but you are passing it an arrays of objects that do not conform to that expectation. Please try saving the children, getting the ids and then using those ids to populate the children field in parent document. Something like below:

```js
children.save()
.then(results => {

childrenids = []
results.foreach[item => childrenids.push(result._id)]
newParent.children = chilrenids
newParent.save()
.then(results => res.send({results})
})
```

Comment: Cleaner than accepted response. However, you could simplify it even more, using `map` instead of `forEach`. ==>`newParent.children = results.map(x => x._id);`